# Thin server on Elastic Beanstalk Runy 2.6 on AMI Linux V2

Tags: ruby, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sinatra, thin

I'm trying to migrate my Sinatra App from the legacy Amazon Linux to V2 on Elastic Beanstalk using the Thin Server. The Thin Server refuses to start on deploy. However, it starts fine and works correctly if I manually start it as the webapp user with the command:

```
bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -C config/thin.yml -V
```

Here are my configuration files:

**.plaform/hooks/prebuild/02_set_permissioms.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Set permissions"
su -s /bin/bash -c "mkdir -p /var/run/thin"
su -s /bin/bash -c "mkdir -p /var/log/thin"
su -s /bin/bash -c "mkdir -p /var/log/thin/rotated"
chown -R webapp:webapp /var/run/thin
chown -R webapp:webapp /var/log/thin
chown -R webapp:webapp /var/log/thin/rotated
```

**.plaform/hooks/03_symlink_pid.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Symlink thin PID to web PID"
set -xe
sudo ln -nsf /var/run/thin/thin.0.0.pid /var/pids/web.pid
```

**.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-ruby-upstream.conf**

```
upstream my_app {
  server unix:///var/run/thin/thin.0.sock;
}
```

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -C config/thin.yml -V
```

**config/thin/yml**

```
---
chdir: /var/app/current
environment: production
address: 0.0.0.0
port: 9292
timeout: 30
log: /var/log/thin/thin.log
pid: /var/run/thin/thin.pid
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 512
require: []
wait: 30
threadpool_size: 20
daemonize: true
socket: /var/run/thin/thin.sock
servers: 1
```

**/var/log/messages**

```
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-adress systemd: Starting This is web daemon...
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-adress systemd: Started This is web daemon.
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-adress systemd: Reloading.
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-adress systemd: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-adress nginx: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-adress nginx: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-adress systemd: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-adress web: NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-adress web: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:45:58 +0000 Starting server on /var/run/thin/thin.0.sock ...
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:45:58 +0000 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/thin start --chdir="/var/app/current" --environment="production" --timeout=30 --log="/var/log/thin/thin.0.log" --pid="/var/run/thin/thin.0.pid" --max-conns=1024 --max-persistent-conns=512 --threadpool-size=20 --rackup="config.ru" --trace --daemonize --socket="/var/run/thin/thin.0.sock"
Jan 12 12:45:59 ip-adress healthd: Version 2 of the Ruby SDK will enter maintenance mode as of November 20, 2020. To continue receiving service updates and new features, please upgrade to Version 3. More information can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deprecation-schedule-for-aws-sdk-for-ruby-v2/
Jan 12 12:45:59 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:45:59 +0000 NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:45:59 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:45:59 +0000 Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:45:59 ip-adress systemd: web.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 12 12:45:59 ip-adress systemd: Stopped This is web daemon.
Jan 12 12:45:59 ip-adress systemd: Starting This is web daemon...
Jan 12 12:45:59 ip-adress systemd: Started This is web daemon.
Jan 12 12:46:00 ip-adress web: NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:00 ip-adress web: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:00 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:00 +0000 Starting server on /var/run/thin/thin.0.sock ...
Jan 12 12:46:00 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:00 +0000 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/thin start --chdir="/var/app/current" --environment="production" --timeout=30 --log="/var/log/thin/thin.0.log" --pid="/var/run/thin/thin.0.pid" --max-conns=1024 --max-persistent-conns=512 --threadpool-size=20 --rackup="config.ru" --trace --daemonize --socket="/var/run/thin/thin.0.sock"
Jan 12 12:46:00 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:00 +0000 NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:00 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:00 +0000 Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-adress systemd: web.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-adress systemd: Stopped This is web daemon.
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-adress systemd: Starting This is web daemon...
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-adress systemd: Started This is web daemon.
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-adress web: NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-adress web: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-adress systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-adress systemd: Started Session 1 of user root.
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:01 +0000 Starting server on /var/run/thin/thin.0.sock ...
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:01 +0000 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/thin start --chdir="/var/app/current" --environment="production" --timeout=30 --log="/var/log/thin/thin.0.log" --pid="/var/run/thin/thin.0.pid" --max-conns=1024 --max-persistent-conns=512 --threadpool-size=20 --rackup="config.ru" --trace --daemonize --socket="/var/run/thin/thin.0.sock"
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-adress CloudWatch-PutInstanceData: Cannot obtain instance id from EC2 meta-data.
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-adress systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:02 +0000 NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:02 +0000 Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-adress systemd: web.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-adress systemd: Stopped This is web daemon.
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-adress systemd: Starting This is web daemon...
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-adress systemd: Started This is web daemon.
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-adress web: NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-adress web: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:02 +0000 Starting server on /var/run/thin/thin.0.sock ...
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:02 +0000 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/thin start --chdir="/var/app/current" --environment="production" --timeout=30 --log="/var/log/thin/thin.0.log" --pid="/var/run/thin/thin.0.pid" --max-conns=1024 --max-persistent-conns=512 --threadpool-size=20 --rackup="config.ru" --trace --daemonize --socket="/var/run/thin/thin.0.sock"
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:03 +0000 NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:03 +0000 Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-adress systemd: web.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-adress systemd: Stopped This is web daemon.
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-adress systemd: Starting This is web daemon...
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-adress systemd: Started This is web daemon.
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-adress web: NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-adress web: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:03 +0000 Starting server on /var/run/thin/thin.0.sock ...
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:03 +0000 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/thin start --chdir="/var/app/current" --environment="production" --timeout=30 --log="/var/log/thin/thin.0.log" --pid="/var/run/thin/thin.0.pid" --max-conns=1024 --max-persistent-conns=512 --threadpool-size=20 --rackup="config.ru" --trace --daemonize --socket="/var/run/thin/thin.0.sock"
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:04 +0000 NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:04 +0000 Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-adress systemd: web.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-adress systemd: Stopped This is web daemon.
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-adress systemd: Starting This is web daemon...
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-adress systemd: Started This is web daemon.
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-adress web: NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-adress web: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:04 +0000 Starting server on /var/run/thin/thin.0.sock ...
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:04 +0000 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/thin start --chdir="/var/app/current" --environment="production" --timeout=30 --log="/var/log/thin/thin.0.log" --pid="/var/run/thin/thin.0.pid" --max-conns=1024 --max-persistent-conns=512 --threadpool-size=20 --rackup="config.ru" --trace --daemonize --socket="/var/run/thin/thin.0.sock"
Jan 12 12:46:05 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:05 +0000 NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:05 ip-adress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:05 +0000 Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:05 ip-adress systemd: web.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 12 12:46:05 ip-adress systemd: Stopped This is web daemon.
Jan 12 12:46:05 ip-adress systemd: start request repeated too quickly for web.service
Jan 12 12:46:05 ip-adress systemd: Failed to start This is web daemon.
Jan 12 12:46:05 ip-adress systemd: Unit web.service entered failed state.
Jan 12 12:46:05 ip-adress systemd: web.service failed.
```

**/var/log/web.stdout.log**

```
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-ddress web: NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-ddress web: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:45:58 +0000 Starting server on /var/run/thin/thin.0.sock ...
Jan 12 12:45:58 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:45:58 +0000 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/thin start --chdir="/var/app/current" --environment="production" --timeout=30 --log="/var/log/thin/thin.0.log" --pid="/var/run/thin/thin.0.pid" --max-conns=1024 --max-persistent-conns=512 --threadpool-size=20 --rackup="config.ru" --trace --daemonize --socket="/var/run/thin/thin.0.sock"
Jan 12 12:45:59 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:45:59 +0000 NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:45:59 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:45:59 +0000 Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:00 ip-ddress web: NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:00 ip-ddress web: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:00 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:00 +0000 Starting server on /var/run/thin/thin.0.sock ...
Jan 12 12:46:00 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:00 +0000 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/thin start --chdir="/var/app/current" --environment="production" --timeout=30 --log="/var/log/thin/thin.0.log" --pid="/var/run/thin/thin.0.pid" --max-conns=1024 --max-persistent-conns=512 --threadpool-size=20 --rackup="config.ru" --trace --daemonize --socket="/var/run/thin/thin.0.sock"
Jan 12 12:46:00 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:00 +0000 NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:00 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:00 +0000 Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-ddress web: NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-ddress web: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:01 +0000 Starting server on /var/run/thin/thin.0.sock ...
Jan 12 12:46:01 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:01 +0000 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/thin start --chdir="/var/app/current" --environment="production" --timeout=30 --log="/var/log/thin/thin.0.log" --pid="/var/run/thin/thin.0.pid" --max-conns=1024 --max-persistent-conns=512 --threadpool-size=20 --rackup="config.ru" --trace --daemonize --socket="/var/run/thin/thin.0.sock"
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:02 +0000 NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:02 +0000 Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-ddress web: NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-ddress web: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:02 +0000 Starting server on /var/run/thin/thin.0.sock ...
Jan 12 12:46:02 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:02 +0000 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/thin start --chdir="/var/app/current" --environment="production" --timeout=30 --log="/var/log/thin/thin.0.log" --pid="/var/run/thin/thin.0.pid" --max-conns=1024 --max-persistent-conns=512 --threadpool-size=20 --rackup="config.ru" --trace --daemonize --socket="/var/run/thin/thin.0.sock"
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:03 +0000 NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:03 +0000 Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-ddress web: NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-ddress web: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:03 +0000 Starting server on /var/run/thin/thin.0.sock ...
Jan 12 12:46:03 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:03 +0000 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/thin start --chdir="/var/app/current" --environment="production" --timeout=30 --log="/var/log/thin/thin.0.log" --pid="/var/run/thin/thin.0.pid" --max-conns=1024 --max-persistent-conns=512 --threadpool-size=20 --rackup="config.ru" --trace --daemonize --socket="/var/run/thin/thin.0.sock"
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:04 +0000 NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:04 +0000 Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-ddress web: NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-ddress web: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:04 +0000 Starting server on /var/run/thin/thin.0.sock ...
Jan 12 12:46:04 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:04 +0000 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/thin start --chdir="/var/app/current" --environment="production" --timeout=30 --log="/var/log/thin/thin.0.log" --pid="/var/run/thin/thin.0.pid" --max-conns=1024 --max-persistent-conns=512 --threadpool-size=20 --rackup="config.ru" --trace --daemonize --socket="/var/run/thin/thin.0.sock"
Jan 12 12:46:05 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:05 +0000 NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed in Rubygems 4
Jan 12 12:46:05 ip-ddress web: 2022-01-12 12:46:05 +0000 Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /var/app/current/vendor/gems/async-rack/async-rack.gemspec:16.
```

The Thin log is empty and does not through out any errors.

Comment: Did you check eb-engine/eb-hooks logs for anything suspicious during the deployment process? Is there anything similar to`/var/log/web*.log` and/or `/var/log/web*.error.log`?

Comment: The web.stdout.log shows the Thin server starting multiple times in the row. Added above. the eb-engine and eb-hooks logs do not show any arrors.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help here, sorry. Is there a way to run `thin` server with logging to stdouut/stderr? As far as I remember EB is quite opinionated and expects services started via Procfile to log to standard channels (it then pipes the output to log files named after the services). I remember some issues with Sidekiq not starting properly on EB Linux2 that I was able to fix only after I remove logging to a file and started to rely on the default EB behavior. Also, try checking systems logs (`journalctl`) - maybe there are some clues there on why `web.service` gets stopped constantly...

Comment: I'm wondering if EB doesn't wait long enough to check if Thin has started. Do you know where/how these settings can be changed? The wait time and the number of retries? I could not figure that out.

Comment: No idea, I don't remember anything like that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to not daemonize the Thin server in config.yml

```
daemonize: false
```